# Process Flat File with Pig

Tags: apache-pig

How do you process a flat file with Pig?  For example, if you had a line containing a record where the first four positions were the year, the next 5 were a product code, and the last 8 contained the MSRP, how would you query this data with Pig?  I'm probably missing something simple, but everything I've found thus far requires a delimiter to be used when loading data with Pig.

Some sample data is provided below:

```
1999ABCDE12234.00
2000DCEFS00020.00
2012FFEWS00005.55
```

Thanks in advance.

Jeremy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to split a line based on positions is to use [REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/func.html#regex-extract-all) .

E.g:

```
A = LOAD 'flat.txt' as (line:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(line, 
      '^(.{1,4})(.{1,5})(.*)$')) AS (year:int, prod_code:chararray, msrp:double);
dump B;
(1999,ABCDE,12234.00)
(2000,DCEFS,00020.00)
(2012,FFEWS,00005.55)
```

Comment: I'm assuming that this approach wouldn't be very efficient and that I would want to store it with a delimiter for future processing, is that correct?

Comment: you could tune this regexp for sure, but if you have the possibility to store the data with delimiters then do that it's definitely more effective than dealing with complex regexps

Answer (score 1):

also, there is a builtin SUBSTRING function,

```
A = LOAD 'flat.txt' as (line:chararray);

B = FOREACH A GENERATE SUBSTRING(line,0,3),SUBSTRING(line,4,8),SUBSTRING(line,9,16);

dump B;
```

Answer (score 0):

Both previous answers are great. Also, you can implement your own UDF if your input string is complicated or conditional parsing is required